# How to retrieve data from UITableview form

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am building a booking app, and here is the UI looks like:

[image: Booking form]

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *identifier;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            identifier=@"noTextField";
            break;
        case 1:
            identifier=@"withTextField";
            break;
        case 2:
            identifier=@"withTextField";
            break;
        case 3:
            identifier=@"noTextField";
            break;
        case 4:
            identifier=@"withTextField";
            break;
        case 5:
            identifier=@"withTextField";
            break;
        default:
            break;
}

TitleCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier    
                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.row) 
{
    case 0:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"Title";
        cell.rightLabel.text = @"Mr";
        cell.rightLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        break;
    case 1:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"FirstName";
        cell.textField.placeholder=@"e.g. John";
        break;
    case 2:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"LastName";
        cell.textField.placeholder=@"e.g. Doe";
        break;
    case 3:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"Birthdate";
        [cell.leftLabel sizeToFit];
        cell.rightLabel.text = @"Sun, 17 Nov 2013";
        cell.rightLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentRight;
        //[cell.rightLabel sizeToFit];
        break;
    case 4:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"Nationality";
        cell.textField.placeholder=@"e.g. Indonesia";
        break;
    case 5:
        cell.leftLabel.text = @"ID Number";
        cell.textField.placeholder=@"e.g. 1234567890";

        break;

    default:
        break;
   }
return cell;
}
```

I am stuck on two problems:

- The `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` seems to be replacing the same identifier cell, so after scrolling some of the `UITextField` will already have a data inside. How do I overcome that? Is it possible to deactivate the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`?
- How do I retrieve the data inside from each sections and cell? I am using a storyboard.

Comment: you can retrieve your previously inserted data by maintaining NSMutableArray of inserted objects. Or also by using NSMutableDictionary and store value of textfield for key as per indexPath

Comment: FYI, it's "passenger," note the "e."

Comment: means what do you want to say?

Comment: Your table view seems very static. Why don't you use a static table view? This will shrink your code extremely, and you can also link your textfields as IBOutlets and directly read their content.

Comment: @Pradhyuman can you demonstrate it on code snippet? where I should retrieve the textfield value? can I iterate all the cell to achieve that?

Comment: @Marc, It's not static, it's very dynamic based on user when chose number of passengers.

Comment: First take the Default array with the count of UITableview row count and set their default value to @""; And then Store UITextField value in array at particular index as per you select textfield row index. And in cellForRowAtIndexPath method just check this array index of indexPath has a @"" value or any other value. IF array has a object than set it as a textfield's text.

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice (although not impossible) to deactivate dequeueReusableCell, since that method is responsible for optimizing the Table View cell allocation. Why do you even need two different cell identifiers? Both types of cell seem to be very similar to me,can't you join them one one?

To solve the problem you should do two things:

1- call `[tableView reloadData];`

2- Set a default value for `cell.textField.text = @""`. This isn't a problem, because when you reload the data, you will overwrite the default value.

Comment: where I should call reloadData? I will try to merge it into one identifier.

Comment: reload the data on viewWillAppear, so that it doesn't get transmitted from one passenger to the other.. did you try simply setting the text to a default value? That should solve your problem..

Comment: Do you mean the cell.textField? because cell.label.text is right as it should be.

Comment: Yes, I mean the cell.textField

Comment: I try that. But now the problem when scrolling, the text will automatically clear from anything, even if I had inserted some string into it. The problem is the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, it's reuse the cell with the same identifier which is shouldn't like that. because every cell is a new cell not reused. Do you know how to overcome that?

Comment: Post your updated class. If the default is overwriting it,you probably did it at the wrong place. The cell.textField.text = @"" should go before the switch..

Answer (score 0):

Usually, to organize table-based form you should keep your data in array, or may be array of arrays (if form is multisection).
The most handy solution is creating a class like FormField that will contain required data and description of what field should be.

Also, you should pass FormFields to your cells or be their delegate and adjust values in your data array on callbacks.

This way you'll have no problems accessing your data.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: I will try your suggestion first. Thanks. By the way is there any ways to do something like this beside using UITableView?

Comment: @xeravim Yes. You can use collection view. Or you can just throw all your form controls onto a scrollview in xib (but it's a bad and dirty way) or layout them programmatically (as dirty as previous, harder and you'll just put your foot under Schrodinger's shotgun). Table is likely to be the best practice.